# Which sensor should I use to detect a ping-pong ball going through a tube?

Tags: sensor

I am working on a game in which a player throws a ping pong ball through a tube. I want to automatically detect it.

I first got a PIR sensor, but that appears to not work well as it was too close and the ball was too small/fast.

I got an ultrasonic sensor. Again, I believe the ball moves too fast and is too small to be accurate.

I got a breakbeam sensor. In theory this seems the most logical but was getting lots of false positives.

I also got a vibration sensor. I liked this a lot as when the ball hit it directly it would vibrate - but I wasn't able to achieve perfect results.

Just curious if anyone has done this before and has ideas! I realize the solution may be more mechanical than electronic. One additional issue is the pipe is at a 45 degree angle so the ball is not necessarily landing on the same bottom/wall every time.

Thanks!

Comment: `I got a breakbeam sensor. In theory this seems the most logical but was getting lots of false positives.` ...... this should have worked ..... how was the sensor wired? ......  how was it installed?

Comment: Also, try positioning your break beam sensor in an angle where you get a bigger length of the beam, and the ball will cut it for a bigger amount of time.

Comment: What type of "break beam" sensor are you using? The ping-pong material might be too transmissive to the light beam being used, painting the ping-pong a darker colour might help the sensor detect it with out needing to turn the sensitivity up so much that you get false positives. Does the system need to work with unmodified ping-pongs or could you, for example, use RFID or NFC tags or maybe embed a magnet in the ball and use a hall-effect sensor?